# terminal keeps saying "The name tf.disable_v2_behavior is deprecated." even though i thought i changed it

Tags: python, gpt-2

I'm very new to using in python (and coding in general past html/css) and I'm not sure how to fix it. I was following a guide on running gpt2 and I got to where I had to import gpt_2_simple as gpt2, but it kept telling me that it was deprecated. sorry if its a newbie question I'm just too tired to figure it out.

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.compat.v1.disable_resource_variables()
```

Not worked.

I'll be honest I gave up and went to sleep after that.

```py
from toposort import toposort
import contextlib
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import time
import sys

# tensorflow 1
try:
    import tensorflow.contrib.graph_editor as ge
# tensorflow 2
except:
    pass

sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)
# refers back to current module if we decide to split helpers out
util = sys.modules[__name__]

# getting rid of "WARNING:tensorflow:VARIABLES collection name is deprecated"
import tensorflow as tf
tf.compat.v1.disable_resource_variables()

# save original gradients since tf.gradient could be monkey-patched to point
# to our version
from tensorflow.python.ops import gradients as tf_gradients_lib
tf_gradients = tf_gradients_lib.gradients

MIN_CHECKPOINT_NODE_SIZE=1024    # use lower value during testing

# specific versions we can use to do process-wide replacement of tf.gradients
def gradients_speed(ys, xs, grad_ys=None, **kwargs):
    return gradients(ys, xs, grad_ys, checkpoints='speed', **kwargs)

def gradients_memory(ys, xs, grad_ys=None, **kwargs):
    return gradients(ys, xs, grad_ys, checkpoints='memory', **kwargs)

def gradients_collection(ys, xs, grad_ys=None, **kwargs):
    return gradients(ys, xs, grad_ys, checkpoints='collection', **kwargs)

def gradients(ys, xs, grad_ys=None, checkpoints='collection', **kwargs):
    '''
    Authors: Tim Salimans & Yaroslav Bulatov

    memory efficient gradient implementation inspired by "Training Deep Nets with Sublinear Memory Cost"
    by Chen et al. 2016 (https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.06174)

    ys,xs,grad_ys,kwargs are the arguments to standard tensorflow tf.gradients
    (https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/train.html#gradients)

    'checkpoints' can either be
        - a list consisting of tensors from the forward pass of the neural net
          that we should re-use when calculating the gradients in the backward pass
          all other tensors that do not appear in this list will be re-computed
        - a string specifying how this list should be determined. currently we support
            - 'speed':  checkpoint all outputs of convolutions and matmuls. these ops are usually the most expensive,
                        so checkpointing them maximizes the running speed
                        (this is a good option if nonlinearities, concats, batchnorms, etc are taking up a lot of memory)
            - 'memory': try to minimize the memory usage
                        (currently using a very simple strategy that identifies a number of bottleneck tensors in the graph to checkpoint)
            - 'collection': look for a tensorflow collection named 'checkpoints', which holds the tensors to checkpoint
    '''

    #    print("Calling memsaving gradients with", checkpoints)
    if not isinstance(ys,list):
        ys = [ys]
    if not isinstance(xs,list):
        xs = [xs]

    bwd_ops = ge.get_backward_walk_ops([y.op for y in ys],
                                       inclusive=True)

    debug_print("bwd_ops: %s", bwd_ops)

    # forward ops are all ops that are candidates for recomputation
    fwd_ops = ge.get_forward_walk_ops([x.op for x in xs],
                                      inclusive=True,
                                      within_ops=bwd_ops)
    debug_print("fwd_ops: %s", fwd_ops)

    # exclude ops with no inputs
    fwd_ops = [op for op in fwd_ops if op.inputs]

    # don't recompute xs, remove variables
    xs_ops = _to_ops(xs)
    fwd_ops = [op for op in fwd_ops if not op in xs_ops]
    fwd_ops = [op for op in fwd_ops if not '/assign' in op.name]
    fwd_ops = [op for op in fwd_ops if not '/Assign' in op.name]
    fwd_ops = [op for op in fwd_ops if not '/read' in op.name]
    ts_all = ge.filter_ts(fwd_ops, True) # get the tensors
    ts_all = [t for t in ts_all if '/read' not in t.name]
    ts_all = set(ts_all) - set(xs) - set(ys)

    # construct list of tensors to checkpoint during forward pass, if not
    # given as input
    if type(checkpoints) is not list:
        if checkpoints == 'collection':
            checkpoints = tf.compat.v1.get_collection('checkpoints')

        elif checkpoints == 'speed':
            # checkpoint all expensive ops to maximize running speed
            checkpoints = ge.filter_ts_from_regex(fwd_ops, 'conv2d|Conv|MatMul')

        elif checkpoints == 'memory':

            # remove very small tensors and some weird ops
            def fixdims(t): # tf.Dimension values are not compatible with int, convert manually
                try:
                    return [int(e if e.value is not None else 64) for e in t]
                except:
                    return [0]  # unknown shape
            ts_all = [t for t in ts_all if np.prod(fixdims(t.shape)) > MIN_CHECKPOINT_NODE_SIZE]
            ts_all = [t for t in ts_all if 'L2Loss' not in t.name]
            ts_all = [t for t in ts_all if 'entropy' not in t.name]
            ts_all = [t for t in ts_all if 'FusedBatchNorm' not in t.name]
            ts_all = [t for t in ts_all if 'Switch' not in t.name]
            ts_all = [t for t in ts_all if 'dropout' not in t.name]
            # DV: FP16_FIX - need to add 'Cast' layer here to make it work for FP16
            ts_all = [t for t in ts_all if 'Cast' not in t.name]

            # filter out all tensors that are inputs of the backward graph
            with util.capture_ops() as bwd_ops:
                tf_gradients(ys, xs, grad_ys, **kwargs)

            bwd_inputs = [t for op in bwd_ops for t in op.inputs]
            # list of tensors in forward graph that is in input to bwd graph
            ts_filtered = list(set(bwd_inputs).intersection(ts_all))
            debug_print("Using tensors %s", ts_filtered)

            # try two slightly different ways of getting bottlenecks tensors
            # to checkpoint
            for ts in [ts_filtered, ts_all]:

                # get all bottlenecks in the graph
                bottleneck_ts = []
                for t in ts:
                    b = set(ge.get_backward_walk_ops(t.op, inclusive=True, within_ops=fwd_ops))
                    f = set(ge.get_forward_walk_ops(t.op, inclusive=False, within_ops=fwd_ops))
                    # check that there are not shortcuts
                    b_inp = set([inp for op in b for inp in op.inputs]).intersection(ts_all)
                    f_inp = set([inp for op in f for inp in op.inputs]).intersection(ts_all)
                    if not set(b_inp).intersection(f_inp) and len(b_inp)+len(f_inp) >= len(ts_all):
                        bottleneck_ts.append(t)  # we have a bottleneck!
                    else:
                        debug_print("Rejected bottleneck candidate and ops %s", [t] + list(set(ts_all) - set(b_inp) - set(f_inp)))

                # success? or try again without filtering?
                if len(bottleneck_ts) >= np.sqrt(len(ts_filtered)): # yes, enough bottlenecks found!
                    break

            if not bottleneck_ts:
                raise Exception('unable to find bottleneck tensors! please provide checkpoint nodes manually, or use checkpoints="speed".')

            # sort the bottlenecks
            bottlenecks_sorted_lists = tf_toposort(bottleneck_ts, within_ops=fwd_ops)
            sorted_bottlenecks = [t for ts in bottlenecks_sorted_lists for t in ts]

            # save an approximately optimal number ~ sqrt(N)
            N = len(ts_filtered)
            if len(bottleneck_ts) <= np.ceil(np.sqrt(N)):
                checkpoints = sorted_bottlenecks
            else:
                step = int(np.ceil(len(bottleneck_ts) / np.sqrt(N)))
                checkpoints = sorted_bottlenecks[step::step]

        else:
            raise Exception('%s is unsupported input for "checkpoints"' % (checkpoints,))

    checkpoints = list(set(checkpoints).intersection(ts_all))

    # at this point automatic selection happened and checkpoints is list of nodes
    assert isinstance(checkpoints, list)

    debug_print("Checkpoint nodes used: %s", checkpoints)
    # better error handling of special cases
    # xs are already handled as checkpoint nodes, so no need to include them
    xs_intersect_checkpoints = set(xs).intersection(set(checkpoints))
    if xs_intersect_checkpoints:
        debug_print("Warning, some input nodes are also checkpoint nodes: %s",
                    xs_intersect_checkpoints)
    ys_intersect_checkpoints = set(ys).intersection(set(checkpoints))
    debug_print("ys: %s, checkpoints: %s, intersect: %s", ys, checkpoints,
                ys_intersect_checkpoints)
    # saving an output node (ys) gives no benefit in memory while creating
    # new edge cases, exclude them
    if ys_intersect_checkpoints:
        debug_print("Warning, some output nodes are also checkpoints nodes: %s",
              format_ops(ys_intersect_checkpoints))

    # remove initial and terminal nodes from checkpoints list if present
    checkpoints = list(set(checkpoints) - set(ys) - set(xs))

    # check that we have some nodes to checkpoint
    # if not checkpoints:
    #     raise Exception('no checkpoints nodes found or given as input! ')

    # disconnect dependencies between checkpointed tensors
    checkpoints_disconnected = {}
    for x in checkpoints:
        if x.op and x.op.name is not None:
            grad_node = tf.stop_gradient(x, name=x.op.name+"_sg")
        else:
            grad_node = tf.stop_gradient(x)
        checkpoints_disconnected[x] = grad_node

    # partial derivatives to the checkpointed tensors and xs
    ops_to_copy = fast_backward_ops(seed_ops=[y.op for y in ys],
                                    stop_at_ts=checkpoints, within_ops=fwd_ops)
    debug_print("Found %s ops to copy within fwd_ops %s, seed %s, stop_at %s",
                    len(ops_to_copy), fwd_ops, [r.op for r in ys], checkpoints)
    debug_print("ops_to_copy = %s", ops_to_copy)
    debug_print("Processing list %s", ys)
    copied_sgv, info = ge.copy_with_input_replacements(ge.sgv(ops_to_copy), {})
    for origin_op, op in info._transformed_ops.items():
        op._set_device(origin_op.node_def.device)
    copied_ops = info._transformed_ops.values()
    debug_print("Copied %s to %s", ops_to_copy, copied_ops)
    ge.reroute_ts(checkpoints_disconnected.values(), checkpoints_disconnected.keys(), can_modify=copied_ops)
    debug_print("Rewired %s in place of %s restricted to %s",
                checkpoints_disconnected.values(), checkpoints_disconnected.keys(), copied_ops)

    # get gradients with respect to current boundary + original x's
    copied_ys = [info._transformed_ops[y.op]._outputs[0] for y in ys]
    boundary = list(checkpoints_disconnected.values())
    dv = tf_gradients(ys=copied_ys, xs=boundary+xs, grad_ys=grad_ys, **kwargs)
    debug_print("Got gradients %s", dv)
    debug_print("for %s", copied_ys)
    debug_print("with respect to %s", boundary+xs)

    inputs_to_do_before = [y.op for y in ys]
    if grad_ys is not None:
        inputs_to_do_before += grad_ys
    wait_to_do_ops = list(copied_ops) + [g.op for g in dv if g is not None]
    my_add_control_inputs(wait_to_do_ops, inputs_to_do_before)

    # partial derivatives to the checkpointed nodes
    # dictionary of "node: backprop" for nodes in the boundary
    d_checkpoints = {r: dr for r,dr in zip(checkpoints_disconnected.keys(),
                                        dv[:len(checkpoints_disconnected)])}
    # partial derivatives to xs (usually the params of the neural net)
    d_xs = dv[len(checkpoints_disconnected):]

    # incorporate derivatives flowing through the checkpointed nodes
    checkpoints_sorted_lists = tf_toposort(checkpoints, within_ops=fwd_ops)
    for ts in checkpoints_sorted_lists[::-1]:
        debug_print("Processing list %s", ts)
        checkpoints_other = [r for r in checkpoints if r not in ts]
        checkpoints_disconnected_other = [checkpoints_disconnected[r] for r in checkpoints_other]

        # copy part of the graph below current checkpoint node, stopping at
        # other checkpoints nodes
        ops_to_copy = fast_backward_ops(within_ops=fwd_ops, seed_ops=[r.op for r in ts], stop_at_ts=checkpoints_other)
        debug_print("Found %s ops to copy within %s, seed %s, stop_at %s",
                    len(ops_to_copy), fwd_ops, [r.op for r in ts],
                    checkpoints_other)
        debug_print("ops_to_copy = %s", ops_to_copy)
        if not ops_to_copy: # we're done!
            break
        copied_sgv, info = ge.copy_with_input_replacements(ge.sgv(ops_to_copy), {})
        for origin_op, op in info._transformed_ops.items():
            op._set_device(origin_op.node_def.device)
        copied_ops = info._transformed_ops.values()
        debug_print("Copied %s to %s", ops_to_copy, copied_ops)
        ge.reroute_ts(checkpoints_disconnected_other, checkpoints_other, can_modify=copied_ops)
        debug_print("Rewired %s in place of %s restricted to %s",
                    checkpoints_disconnected_other, checkpoints_other, copied_ops)

        # gradient flowing through the checkpointed node
        boundary = [info._transformed_ops[r.op]._outputs[0] for r in ts]
        substitute_backprops = [d_checkpoints[r] for r in ts]
        dv = tf_gradients(boundary,
                          checkpoints_disconnected_other+xs,
                          grad_ys=substitute_backprops, **kwargs)
        debug_print("Got gradients %s", dv)
        debug_print("for %s", boundary)
        debug_print("with respect to %s", checkpoints_disconnected_other+xs)
        debug_print("with boundary backprop substitutions %s", substitute_backprops)

        inputs_to_do_before = [d_checkpoints[r].op for r in ts]
        wait_to_do_ops = list(copied_ops) + [g.op for g in dv if g is not None]
        my_add_control_inputs(wait_to_do_ops, inputs_to_do_before)

        # partial derivatives to the checkpointed nodes
        for r, dr in zip(checkpoints_other, dv[:len(checkpoints_other)]):
            if dr is not None:
                if d_checkpoints[r] is None:
                    d_checkpoints[r] = dr
                else:
                    d_checkpoints[r] += dr
        def _unsparsify(x):
            if not isinstance(x, tf.IndexedSlices):
                return x
            assert x.dense_shape is not None, "memory_saving_gradients encountered sparse gradients of unknown shape"
            indices = x.indices
            while indices.shape.ndims < x.values.shape.ndims:
                indices = tf.expand_dims(indices, -1)
            return tf.scatter_nd(indices, x.values, x.dense_shape)

        # partial derivatives to xs (usually the params of the neural net)
        d_xs_new = dv[len(checkpoints_other):]
        for j in range(len(xs)):
            if d_xs_new[j] is not None:
                if d_xs[j] is None:
                    d_xs[j] = _unsparsify(d_xs_new[j])
                else:
                    d_xs[j] += _unsparsify(d_xs_new[j])


    return d_xs

def tf_toposort(ts, within_ops=None):
    all_ops = ge.get_forward_walk_ops([x.op for x in ts], within_ops=within_ops)

    deps = {}
    for op in all_ops:
        for o in op.outputs:
            deps[o] = set(op.inputs)
    sorted_ts = toposort(deps)

    # only keep the tensors from our original list
    ts_sorted_lists = []
    for l in sorted_ts:
        keep = list(set(l).intersection(ts))
        if keep:
            ts_sorted_lists.append(keep)

    return ts_sorted_lists

def fast_backward_ops(within_ops, seed_ops, stop_at_ts):
    bwd_ops = set(ge.get_backward_walk_ops(seed_ops, stop_at_ts=stop_at_ts))
    ops = bwd_ops.intersection(within_ops).difference([t.op for t in stop_at_ts])
    return list(ops)

@contextlib.contextmanager
def capture_ops():
  """Decorator to capture ops created in the block.
  with capture_ops() as ops:
    # create some ops
  print(ops) # => prints ops created.
  """

  micros = int(time.time()*10**6)
  scope_name = str(micros)
  op_list = []
  with tf.compat.v1.name_scope(scope_name):
    yield op_list

  g = tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph()
  op_list.extend(ge.select_ops(scope_name+"/.*", graph=g))

def _to_op(tensor_or_op):
  if hasattr(tensor_or_op, "op"):
    return tensor_or_op.op
  return tensor_or_op

def _to_ops(iterable):
  if not _is_iterable(iterable):
    return iterable
  return [_to_op(i) for i in iterable]

def _is_iterable(o):
  try:
    _ = iter(o)
  except Exception:
    return False
  return True

DEBUG_LOGGING=False
def debug_print(s, *args):
  """Like logger.log, but also replaces all TensorFlow ops/tensors with their
  names. Sensitive to value of DEBUG_LOGGING, see enable_debug/disable_debug

  Usage:
    debug_print("see tensors %s for %s", tensorlist, [1,2,3])
  """

  if DEBUG_LOGGING:
    formatted_args = [format_ops(arg) for arg in args]
    print("DEBUG "+s % tuple(formatted_args))

def format_ops(ops, sort_outputs=True):
  """Helper method for printing ops. Converts Tensor/Operation op to op.name,
  rest to str(op)."""

  if hasattr(ops, '__iter__') and not isinstance(ops, str):
    l = [(op.name if hasattr(op, "name") else str(op)) for op in ops]
    if sort_outputs:
      return sorted(l)
    return l
  else:
    return ops.name if hasattr(ops, "name") else str(ops)

def my_add_control_inputs(wait_to_do_ops, inputs_to_do_before):
    for op in wait_to_do_ops:
        ci = [i for i in inputs_to_do_before if op.control_inputs is None or i not in op.control_inputs]
        ge.add_control_inputs(op, ci)
```

this is the full code

```
>>> import gpt_2_simple as gpt2
2024-03-10 21:27:51.824359: I tensorflow/core/util/port.cc:113] oneDNN custom operations are on. You may see slightly different numerical results due to floating-point round-off errors from different computation orders. To turn them off, set the environment variable `TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0`.
2024-03-10 21:27:53.644202: I tensorflow/core/util/port.cc:113] oneDNN custom operations are on. You may see slightly different numerical results due to floating-point round-off errors from different computation orders. To turn them off, set the environment variable `TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0`.
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\gpt_2_simple\src\memory_saving_gradients.py:20: The name tf.GraphKeys is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.GraphKeys instead.
```

the error message

Comment: but in the code you posted you are not importing gpt_2_ simple as gpt2. Your question and the code you posted doesn't seem to be related.

Comment: I was told to run import gpt_2_simple as gpt2, and i did, but it kept showing me that error. again, sorry, im vewy new to python

Comment: no you didn't. In the posted code you are not  importing gpt_2_simple as gpt. Also what error are you referring to? You need to edit your question, post the code you are executing and the complete traceback of any error you are getting

Comment: yes, in that code im not. im showing the code that the error is highlighting

Comment: Please edit your question and add the exact code you are executing and the exact error traceback you are getting

Comment: is this better?

Comment: Well, I can see a deprecation Warning but no errors. That's not an error and your code should run fine.

Comment: it does not run fine, the process just comes to a halt and i cannot proceed

Comment: so your question is about the code coming to a halt. which you don't mention anywhere in your question, although is the issue you are actually facing. Have you debugged the code line by line to determine where it comes to a halt? This is the very first step you should do when encountering issues in code.

Comment: the code itself doesnt halt, the process does, with it saying the reason is the problem in the title. again, im not very well-versed in python or coding in general

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).